# Assign argument function to class member

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have a class that contains a pointer to function as its member as follows:

```
class demo{
    void (*fn_ptr) (int) = NULL;        
    void AssignPtr(void (*fptr)(int))
    {
      *fn_ptr = *fptr;
    }
};
```

And I get error:

`error: cannot convert ‘void(int)’ to ‘void(int)’ in assignment`

Comment: Functions are not objects. You can't assign to functions.

Comment: It's a reference not assignment I want the member pointer to refer to the function to be able to call it later

Comment: @SamehKamal: Then assign the pointer; don't reference it and try to assign the function it points to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you meant to just assign the pointer:

```
fn_ptr = fptr;
```

As in:

```
class demo {
    void (*fn_ptr)(int) = NULL;

public:
    void AssignPtr(void (*fptr)(int))
    {   
        fn_ptr = fptr;
    }   

    void Call(int i) {
        fn_ptr(i);
    }   
};

void print(int x) {
    std::cout << "called print(" << x << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    demo d;
    d.AssignPtr(print);
    d.Call(42);
}
```